# How to set right property of loadgo.js to left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

May i know that how can i set the `right` property of `.loadgo-overlay` to `left`? I followed all the instruction to implement the loadgo animation. However, the animation is appeared on the right hand side instead of appear together with the image which is left hand side. I even tried to modify the values to `left:0px; right:none;` in loadgo.js file when the code is trying to create a `<div>`, though the style of the loadgo-overlay has added the left property but the `right` property still become to 0px even tho i changed to none. My expected result will be the animation to appear together with the image on left hand side.

[image: loadgo-overlay property]

partial of loadgo.js:

```
var overlayTemplate = '<div class="loadgo-overlay" style="background-color:%bgcolor%;opacity:%opacity%;width:%width%px;height:%height%px;position:absolute;"></div>';

var overlayWithOptions =
  overlayTemplate
    .replace('%bgcolor%', pluginOptions.bgcolor)
    .replace('%opacity%', pluginOptions.opacity)
    .replace('%width%', _w)
    .replace('%height%', _h);

$overlay = $(overlayWithOptions);
```

Here,is my fiddle to test the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/4vfxfjxr/5/

**Expected result**
[image: what i wanted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding CSS on .loadgo-overlay, Should add CSS on .loadgo-container. Because loadgo-overlay's parent is loadgo-container. For more information please refer to jsfiddle as provided.

```
.loadgo-container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4vfxfjxr/9/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `direction` attribute and set to to `rl` for left to right animation, It should look like,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#header').loadgo(
    {
      'direction':    'rl'
    }
  );
    $('#header').loadgo('loop', 20);

});
```

**Working Demo is available here:** https://jsfiddle.net/qx835keg/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi, it still doesn't work. why the animation still appears on the right hand side? i would like to have the animation stick together with the image....

Comment: when i changed the direction to 'rl', it somehow appears on left hand side but the transition is not what i wanted. so please help...

Comment: Do you mean to say, only a right to left animation (one time only) is needed? no looping?

Comment: No, i mean i would like to have the left to right animation on top of the image. by default the animation is left to right, but the result is appeared on right hand side and what i expected to be on top of my image...

Comment: Please refer to the image that i just added.

Comment: Sure... Checking

Comment: The library shows the animation only over the image which means it will not extend it to the parent div. Also since the logo is white in color, the overlay effect is kind of giving us a feel of not working. I've replaced the logo (with a darker background) .. which will give you a clear picture => https://jsfiddle.net/qx835keg/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4vfxfjxr/5/, Hi, i added some code to enable you to understand the animation more clearer. the direction of the animation that i want is from `left` to `right`. but it still appear on the left hand side tho. please refer to johannes's answer. Although his location is correct by fixing the css. However, i think the fixing did conflict with their own css. So it doesnt animate correctly from left to right even tho i set the direction from left to right.... Thank you for helping me. please help me againn...

Answer (score 0):

If you add this CSS, the animation appears in the logo/image on the left side:

```
.loadgo-overlay {
  left: 0px;
  right: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4vfxfjxr/2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4vfxfjxr/4/, i changed the method a little bit. Your location for the loadgo is correct but the animation is wrong although i set the direction to lr, still not working as well..... please help..

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't help you any further - I simply don't know that loadgo library...

Comment: Hi, i want to start the animation from left to right... not load from right to left. https://jsfiddle.net/4vfxfjxr/5/, i changed the image for more understanding. By right, the animation should load from alphabet A until alphabet I. Based on your answer, the animation is loaded from right to left which is not smoothly.... If you are still cannot get what i said, i can draw an image to show you how the animation should be.